# Run multiple instances of Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, multiple-instances

I have both Photoshop CC and Photoshop CS6 installed on my machine.

Sometimes I have to scan things with CS6 because it's 32bit and rely on some things (twain32 but also other plugins) and have Photoshop CC to do other works.

Because seemingly Photoshop checks for something like Photoshop.exe already running the other one isn't loaded unless I close the previous first. This is stupid, annoying and irritating.

Plus I like to script a lot of jsx files to automate lot of things inside photoshop, photoshop itself processes things very slow (lot of things are still not multithreaded in 2021 or maybe not multithreadeable...) so I have to wait a lot before each script could get completed.

Would be nice run so various instances of Photoshop to feed properly my Threadripper machine and carry out the tasks fastly...

So... there's any know way, hack, registry flag, whatever thing to make able photoshop run in multiple instances without creating problems?

Bonus: Have the same thing work for Illustrator, Indesign and few other main programs of the CC suite would be gold.

Thanks for your interest :)

Comment: Have you tried renaming either of exe files?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov tried, with no success... anyway even if that would have worked I would have been able to run just the 2 photoshop versions, better than nothing but my aim is free multiple instances

Comment: Evidently the program is not coded to run multiple instances, nothing you can do.

Comment: Run the CS versions in a VM. Problem solved.

Comment: @Tetsujin I know this is an option but I would have avoided that because there's such a ton of overhead just for accomplish a banal multithread.

Comment: You're fighting that the OS sees them as versions of the same thing - something that can only be effectively changed at compile. I don't see there's another alternative.

Comment: @Tetsujin I've heard of a program called Sandboxie https://github.com/sandboxie/sandboxie that effectively replicates part of underlying execution layers hence allows Photoshop to be runned multiple times. But you know the developers maybe put a less documented register key, or a command line switch or something else that could allow to run multiple instances. Just like you can do with Firefox via editing some xml files. Here I ask if someone knows that. I'm considering also to alter the program via a patch if this could be doable and useful.

Comment: VM is not a solution, it's a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install SandBoxie Plus
2. Open SandBoxie Plus
3. Right Click DefaultBox
4. Run
5. Run Program
6. Add Photoshop.exe Path, OK
7. Right Click Photoshop.exe in SandBoxie
8. Create and Save Shortcut

For Multiple Instances Create New Boxes and repeat process

Comment: To me it's becoming a bit spammie when you are posting the same answer to so many questions.

Comment: Ok, just trying to help so people can solve their problems as fast as they can, no matter where the answer is located, sorry.